# ReportMissingImports -- Python virtual environment cant find my Imports

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to use a virtual environment in vscode, but when I set the interpreter to the file path in my venv folder it says that the imports can't be resolved? I am installing the packages via pip in my bash prompt outside of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, selecting python interpreter in same folder venv; for select interpreter <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>